# Wi-Fi Scanner Android Application

Tags: android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifi

I created an Android App which shows the list of available networks and provide me the connectivity to a specific WiFi network after entering wifi password. But the problem which I'm facing that my app does not keep my given wifi password save.
The code of my application is given below:

```
 private void finallyConnect(String networkPass, String networkSSID) {
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPass);

    // remember id
    int netId = mainWifiObj.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    mainWifiObj.disconnect();
    mainWifiObj.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    mainWifiObj.reconnect();

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"\"" + networkSSID + "\"\"";
    conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
    mainWifiObj.addNetwork(conf);
}

private void connectToWifi(final String wifiSSID) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.connect);
    dialog.setTitle("Connect to Network");
    TextView textSSID = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textSSID1);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
    pass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
    textSSID.setText(wifiSSID);

    // if button is clicked, connect to the network;
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String checkPassword = pass.getText().toString();
            finallyConnect(checkPassword, wifiSSID);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

    findMyip();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any specifics you need help debugging? Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should probably include some aspects of your code or screen shots of the app and explain fully in detail what is what.

Comment: sir kindly check my application code and give me some guidance....